# How do I disable retina mode/HiDPI on macOS Mojave on the built-in display of a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, mojave, resolution

I want to test non-retina/non-HiDPI mode on macOS Mojave on the built-in display of a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017). I found articles that suggest enabling the option `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true`, restarting the computer, opening `System Preferences`, selecting `Displays`, and holding down the `option ⌥` key when selecting `Scaled` should show a list of all available resolutions, including non-HiDPI resolutions; however, I just see the following:

[image: Screenshot of displays]

Comment: Meaning you want to select the screen's native resolution?

Comment: I'm not very versed in topics of resolution, but it seems my "native resolution" is 2880x1800 but I got the result I wanted by using the app you recommended and selected 1440x900.

Comment: That would mean your question was falsely flagged as duplicate. If you elaborate your question a bit, I guess you could notify a mod to have it unflagged. But please check if there is not another similar question ;)

Comment: I start to understand, although I am not sure what you could need that for? 1440x900 is what is "simulated", when you select `Default for display`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the free App [Display Menu](http://displaymenu.milchimgemuesefach.de).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I opened `About This Mac`, clicked on `Displays`, observed the resolution noted there, and then selected the resolution that halved both of these numbers from the `Display Menu` app.